# Post character creation, getting spellcraft bonuses

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

After character creation what is a good way to get bonuses to spellcraft? I'd rather not have to use feats, however.

Are there any items, equipment, spells or suchlike that could be used? Such as maybe [foxes cunning](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/foxSCunning.html) - however with the short duration it's not really useful for item creation as this is going to be the character's focus.

Extra: The character is an Elven Wizard Universalist. Campaign setting is Kingmaker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can't or don't want to expend feats, then you are left with very few choices.

Synergy bonus has been removed from the [pathfinder](/questions/tagged/pathfinder)'s skill systems, so maximizing your Knowledge (Arcana) does not help.

However, you can forge or commission a [custom magic item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values)<sup>D20PFSRD</sup>. The key formula is

> Skill bonus (competence) | Bonus squared x 100 gp

So, for example, a *Diadem of Dweomercraft +10* could be commissioned or bought for 10'000 gp (or crafted for half that value).

Comment: I rather like the idea of that; a +5 to spellcraft item would be fairly cheap to make and a good start to my characters magic item creation career. :)

Comment: +1 Just keep in mind that magic item creation doesn't fit into some campaigns. NPCs won't have this item lying around, and unless you return often to the same city, or have a time lapse of great enough time, many times it's impossible to have the item created.

Comment: @Dan My plan is to actually make said item first, then make other stuff :)

Answer (score 7):

## Items granting a bonus to the skill [Spellcraft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/spellcraft)

- Praying at an ***altar of Nethys*** (*Inner Sea Gods* 248) grants, among other bonuses, a +2 circumstance bonus on Spellcraft checks. The *altar* is reasonably priced but weighs 500 lbs.
- Consulting an [**arcane family workbook**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/books-paper-writing-supplies#TOC-Book) grants a +2 or +4 circumstance bonus on Spellcraft skill checks.
- Wearing an [***armillary amulet***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-armillary) grants a +5 competence bonus on Spellcraft skill checks and is the cheapest item granting such a bonus.
- Praying at a **masterwork portable altar** (*Demon Hunter's Handbook* 18) to Nethys grants a +2 circumstance bonus on Spellcraft skill checks.
- Employing a [**masterwork tool**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/tools-kits#TOC-Tool-Masterwork) for the skill Spellcraft grants a +2 circumstance bonus on Spellcraft skill checks. This is *so* dirt cheap you should already have one.
- Wielding a [***scimitar of the spellthief***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/scimitar-of-the-spellthief) grants a +2 bonus on Spellcraft skill checks, but the weapon is outrageously expensive.

[Circumstance bonuses stack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus) unless circumstances are similar. Maybe in the GM's campaign [Nethys](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Nethys) is particularly generous if prayed to at different altars? Good luck.

(If needed for item creation, its unlikely the situational insight bonuses granted by the [*headband of counterspelling*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-counterspelling) and the [*orb of arcane research*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/orb-of-arcane-research) will be helpful, but they're out there.)

Comment: Thanks for the list; I've also found you can get bonuses from Ultimate Campaign from Fame as well! My character can ace any spellcraft roll sent at him now anyway; it's just making his bonus as insane as possible now ;)

Answer (score 5):

Rather indirect and impractical, the [Wish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wish) spell can nevertheless be used to get a permanent, inherent bonus to an attribute (such as INT), which will raise your spellcraft score accordingly.

Comment: Something to think about in the characters later years, thanks!